# Need to get the image from server by API link (The image is published with backend to Aure)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

I created a project ASP NET CORE WEB API 6.0. I created a folder 'Image' and save the png picture there. Now I wont to get this image by link. API was published to AZURE, and I want to get the image by link like 'apilnk/Image/test.png', but looks like I need to make the folder publis first. How can i configure app.UseStaticFiles to do this? Or I need some more settings.

Thank you.

I am expecting to display an image using url 'apiurl/Image/someimage.png'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily define an action and handle all logic you have for download with that. This sample code explains how you can do that.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class FileDownloadController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _environment;

    public FileDownloadController(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        _environment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{fileName}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadImage(string fileName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "Image", fileName);
        var fileAsByteArray = await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath, cancellationToken);
        var fileProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
        if (fileProvider.TryGetContentType(fileName, out string contentType) is false)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Unable to find Content Type for file name {fileName}.");
        }

        return File(fileAsByteArray, contentType);
    }
}
```